# How to convert array byte to string in c ++?

Tags: c++-cli

```
byte S[5] = {0x48, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x6C}
```

I want to know how to convert the above byte array to a string.

When converting the above byte array to a string, `"Hello"` should be output.

I tried various ways but it didn't solve at all.

1. `String^ a = System::Convert::ToString(S);`
2. `std::string s(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (S), 5);`

A completely different string is output. What should I do?

Comment: `String^ a = System::Convert::ToString(S);` doesn't look like C++.

Comment: Why should `hello` be printined?  You have two `0x00` in the array which ar null terminators.

Comment: What encoding are you using?  ASCII is 7-bits.

Comment: Added the "c++-cli" tag because `String^` is not valid syntax for pure C++, but is valid for Microsoft abominations.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using a brute-force approach?  For example, iterate through the array, if the byte is not a nul, append it to the string.

Comment: `0x48, 0x00,` looks a lot like 16 bit wide character rather than the regular 8 bit representation you may be used to. See if `std::wstring` can help you out. If not, it's time [to delve into locales](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert C++ byte array to a C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399227/convert-c-byte-array-to-a-c-string)

Comment: Like this:
std::string{ &s[0], &s[std::size(s)] } You might lose last character, strings are null terminated.

Comment: When converting to std::string your string will be cut off by the 0x00 character. This is counted as a null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: That byte array doesn't contain "Hello". It looks like half of the 10 bytes needed to encode 5 Unicode characters in UTF-16.

For converting between bytes and strings in .Net, including C++/CLI, you want to use the [`Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding) classes. Based on the data you've shown here, you'll want to use [`Encoding::Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode). To convert from bytes to a string, call [`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring).

```
byte S[5] = {0x48, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x6C};
```

Because you used the `[]` syntax, this is a raw C array, not a .Net managed array object. Therefore, you'll need to use the overload that takes a raw pointer and a length.

```
String^ str = Encoding::Unicode->GetString(S, 5);
```

If you use a .Net array object, calling it will be a bit easier, as the array class knows its length.

```
array<Byte>^ S = gcnew array<Byte> { 0x48, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x6C };
String^ str = Encoding::Unicode->GetString(S);
```